Hide Office 365 ribbon / suit bar on MS Teams Web
We need to show MS Team (Web) inside SharePoint Modern Portal. We were thinking to embed it in a web instead of opening a new tab to meet client's few expectations.
We are trying to hide Office 365 ribbon / suit bar by using HideNavbar = true in the URL https://teams.microsoft.com/v2/ but it is not working.
Kindly suggest if there is any alternate for it.
Thanks
